# index trees with c++/boost

Tags: c++, boost

I want to do the next tree:

```
                                      1     
                    1.1                                 1.2  
       1.1.1                 1.1.2          1.2.1                1.2.2
 1.1.1.1   1.1.1.2                                         1.2.2.1   1.2.2.2
```

at the end I have the list with the final level of all index as follows,(in disorder):

```
1.2.2.2
1.2.2.1
1.1.1.2
1.2.1        
1.1.2 
1.1.1.1
```

How to use a boost library to index in this way and sort them like this:

```
1.1.1.1 
1.1.1.2
1.1.2 
1.2.1   
1.2.2.1   
1.2.2.2
```

Comment: [what have you tried so far?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: what specifically are you having problems with?

Comment: I'm just reading a boots' manual.

Comment: Well how to index in this form and after that how to sort this kind of index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really think you need to use Boost, the obvious place to go would be the [Boost Graph Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/graph/doc/index.html). In all honesty, however, this strikes as a bit like using nuclear weapons to kill mosquitoes.

The first part is a simple binary tree that doesn't even require balancing, so it's just a matter of traversing and inserting items where appropriate. Getting the result is about equally simple -- traverse the tree, and add a node to the output if and only if it's a leaf.

Sorting the result takes `std::sort` along with a comparison function that compares the individual elements in each item. If you're sure each element will only be a single digit, you can use a simple lexical comparison instead.

Comment: The problem is how to use std::sort to sort this type of indexing.

Comment: @user1310873: As I said, you basically need to break the string up into pieces (separated by the '.'s), convert each piece to a number, and then compare those numbers. As I also said, if each piece will always be a single digit, you can just do a normal string comparison instead (but you probably don't want that, because it'll break if you get a double-digit number).

Comment: Ok I realized that if i add 0 to indexes which have less digits like the other one I can sort them. 
1111 
1112
1120 
1210   
1221   
1222